# COPY function in FOR loop (batch)

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, copy

I am working on a batch script which would synchronize 2 folders. What i mean by synchronize is: the script will compare each file of each folder and it will keep only the most recent one in each folder. Its basically a *smart* backup program.

Here is the part of my code that i am having trouble with (The whole script can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/pBvQjkUB)):

```
for /d /r %drivePath% %%d in (*) do (
  set currentDriveFolderPath=%%d
  if not exist "%devicePath%!currentDriveFolderPath:~%driveLength%!" (
    mkdir "%devicePath%!currentDriveFolderPath:~%driveLength%!"
  )
  for %%f in (*.*) do (
    set currentFile=%%f
    if exist "%devicePath%!currentDriveFolderPath:~%driveLength%!!currentFile!" (
      set currentDriveFile="!currentDriveFolderPath!\!currentFile!"
      set currentDeviceFile="%devicePath%!currentDriveFolderPath:~%driveLength%!!currentFile!"
      call:compareModifiedDate !currentDriveFile! !currentDeviceFile!
      if !recent! == file1 (
        copy /y !currentDriveFile! !currentDeviceFile!
      ) else if !recent! == file2 (
        copy /y !currentDeviceFile! !currentDriveFile!
      )
    ) else (
      set source
      copy /y !currentDriveFile! !currentDeviceFile!
    )
  )
)

for /d /r %devicePath% %%d in (*) do (
  set currentDeviceFolderPath=%%d
  if not exist %drivePath%!currentDeviceFolderPath:~%deviceLength%! (
    mkdir "%drivePath%!currentDeviceFolderPath:~%deviceLength%!"
    for %%f in (*.*) do (
      set currentFile=%%f
      if not exist "%drivePath%!currentDeviceFolderPath:~%DeviceLength%!!currentFile!" (
        copy /y !currentDriveFile! !currentDeviceFile!
      )
    )
  )
)
```

My question is: **what can i do to call the COPY function inside a FOR loop with the source and destination paths changing each time?**

Comment: Batch, or Bash? Two separate things

Comment: @UnknownOctopus - Well, the script is obviously not bash, and if you know anything about Windows batch scripting, you would instantly recognize it as such. Also, the OP consistently uses the term batch and batch script, and used the batch-file tag. Why would you speculate that the question could be anything other than a Windows batch script?

Comment: @dbenham Because OP's link uses bash highlighting. That's why. And tag's aren't always correct, they have been misused many, many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to even try to figure out your code - it is too painful - knowing that there is a much simpler solution.

I believe all you need are two simple XCOPY statements, one in each direction, with the /D option to get both folder hierarchies to synchronize with the most recent versions of each file in each. There is more to flesh out, but I think this should get you on your way. You could also use ROBOCOPY in a similar fashion - it gives lots more options and is more robust, but it is also more complex syntax to get what you want.

Assume your root paths are `d:\path1` and `e:\path2`

```
xcopy d:\path1 e:\path2 /e /d /y
xcopy e:\path2 d:\path1 /e /d /y
```

I've done some rudimentary testing, and it appears to work, but I've not done rigorous testing. Be sure to run plenty of tests to make sure I haven't missed something.

Comment: Thanks a lot @dbenham!!! I am still new to batch so i didnt know that the /d option in the xcopy command existed... and thats also why my code is such a mess. But could you tell me if it is possible to do a copy command inside a for loop like i asked?

Comment: It is possible with `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`.

Comment: Also consider using `call :SOMELABEL param1 param2` in order to use SOMELABEL as a sort of function.  You need to understand what `call` will do in this case.  Run `call /?` for the help.